# JUnit Test - ParameterizedTests - 'No implicit conversion of type java.lang.Integer to type [Ljava.lang.Integer;'

Tags: java, testing, junit

Using JUnit5. This doesn't seem to be behaving correctly to me, I'm likely missing something.

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void testFunc(Integer arr []) {
        for(Integer i : arr){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> testFunc() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(new Integer [] {12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425, 4}),
                Arguments.of(new Integer [] {12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425}),
                Arguments.of(new Integer [] {12})
        );
    }
```

Produces the error:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type java.lang.Integer to type [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

I've also tried the above code using `int` instead of `Integer`, but this works correctly.

This works with no error:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        test(new Integer []{12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425, 4});
    }

    static void test(Integer[] arr) {
        for(Integer a : arr){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think so, MethodSource tells a ParameterizedTest where to look for arguments. I tried the same code above using ints instead of Integers and it worked correctly.

Comment: This is a feature of JUnit 5, https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource "If you do not explicitly provide a factory method name via MethodSource, JUnit Jupiter will search for a factory method that has the same name as the current ParameterizedTest method by convention. This is demonstrated in the following example."

Comment: I tried changing the name of the Stream method to "testFuncArgs", then added MethodSource("testFuncArgs") on the Test function, but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting this error, because the method declaration of [`Arguments.of()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/Arguments.html) is the following:

```java
public static Arguments of(Object... arguments)
```

`Object...` indicates a varargs (variable arguments) parameter, so when writing:

```java
Arguments.of(1, 2, 3)
```

at compile time, java will desuger this into an array:

```java
Arguments.of(new Object[]{1, 2, 3})
```

The problem that you're having can be shown by the following:

```java
Integer[] ints = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3};
Object[] objs = ints; // works
```

So when you write:

```java
Arguments.of(new Integer[]{12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425, 4})
```

Then java will just pass this array directly into the method, it would effectively behave the same as both of the following:

```java
Arguments.of(new Object[]{12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425, 4})
Arguments.of(12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425, 4)
```

To overcome this problem, you need to cast your `Integer[]` array directly to `Object`, that way it will be wrapped inside another array:

```java
Arguments.of((Object) new Integer[]{12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425, 4})
```

Will become:

```java
Arguments.of(new Object[]{new Integer[]{12, 42, 52, 1234, 12, 425, 4}})
```

As you've noted it works correctly with `int[]` because the following doesn't work:

```
int[] ints = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
Object[] objs = ints; // int[] cannot be assigned to Object[]
```

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you so much for your help!